# How to work with Radio Group on RibbonControl winform devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

In my Form I add RibbonControl. I need to work with RadioButton in that RibbonControl Group. In normal MS Visual Studio radiobox I wrote code like this

```
if(gender.Checked) {//code} on CheckedChanged Event
```

but i didn't find checkedChanged Event in RadioGruop in Ribbon Control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `EditValueChanged` event and `EditValue` of `BarEditItem` will be having the value of `RadioGroupItem`.

Or use `SelectedIndexChanged` of `RepositoryItemRadioGroup`

```
repositoryItemRadioGroup1.SelectedIndexChanged += repositoryItemRadioGroup1_SelectedIndexChanged;
void repositoryItemRadioGroup1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)sender;
    int index = rg.SelectedIndex;
    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
}
```

You may find this helpful. http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q295970

Comment: Hi Sriram, I have doubt in RadiotGroup. In BeforeLeaveRow Event I have code to calculate Total, this Total is different calculation according to selected RadioButton in the RadioGroup. I dono how to perform this, Help me.

Comment: For example I need to get the Selected RadioButton and then perform calculation. `IF(BarEditItem1.Index=0) { //code }else if(BarEditItem1.Index=0) {//code} `  like this.

Comment: @SriHari Raise a new question with explaining about the problem and link it here i'll look at it

Comment: [Link-Problem on Working with RadioGroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567669/how-to-work-with-radiogroup-in-ribboncontrol-in-winforms-devexpress)