# How to work with RadioGroup in RibbonControl in WInforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, radio-group, ribbon-control

Hi, I need RadioButton on Ribbon Control so I used RadioGroup and created event `selectedIndexChanged`, In which I performed some tasks

```
 private void repositoryItemRadioGroup1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)sender;
        int index = rg.SelectedIndex;

        if (index == 0)
        {
             // code
        }
        if (index == 1)
        {
           // code              
        }
        if (index == 2)
        {
           // code       
        }
        else if (!(index == 2) || !(index == 1))
        {
           // code
        }
    }
```

Till now the code work fine.in `beforeLeaveRow` event I am performing some calculations but I need to perform the calculations based on the Radio Button Selected so I need to get that Selected Radio Button and then perform calculations based on what I selected.

eg

```
private void gridView1_BeforeLeaveRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowAllowEventArgs e)
    {          
        decimal a = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_SubTotal.Text);
        decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Shipping.Text);
        decimal c = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Tax.Text);
        decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Discount.Text);
        if(RadioGroup.index==0)
        {
        total = ((a + b + c) - d).ToString("n2"); 
        }
        else if(RadioGroup.index==1)
        {
         total = (a + b + c).ToString("n2");
        }
    }
```

I need to perform calculations like this. Help me complete my task. How to get Selected RadioIndex or something ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show how you populated the `RadioGroup`, answer depends on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is desired code:

```
repositoryItemRadioGroup1.Items.AddRange(new RadioGroupItem[] 
{
     new RadioGroupItem(1, "Item1"),
     new RadioGroupItem(2, "Item2")
});

private void gridView1_BeforeLeaveRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.RowAllowEventArgs e)
{ 
    if(barEditItemRadio.EditValue==null)
       return;//Or do whatever 
    int editValue = (int)barEditItemRadio.EditValue;
    if(editValue ==1)//Item1 is selected 
    {
    total = ((a + b + c) - d).ToString("n2"); 
    }
    else if(editValue ==2)//Item2is selected 
    {
     total = (a + b + c).ToString("n2");
    }
}
```

Comment: error showing on this line `int editValue = (int)barEditItem1.EditValue;` as Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @SriHari As I shown you you should add `RadioGroupItem` like this. Look at the first parameter, it is integer. What you have added?

Comment: Hi, Sriram thanks I got now. In RadioGroup Item Value i used string before so error came now I changed and get expected result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Sriram, I have another doubt I want to store this radio Button to access database and want to retrieve it. [How2Store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593344/how-to-store-and-retrieve-the-radiogroup-radio-button-and-checkbox-of-ribbon-con)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.