# How to store and retrieve the RadioGroup Radio Button and CheckBox of Ribbon Control from Winforms Devexpress to MS Access Database?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, radio-group, ribbon-control

In my form I used Ribbon control in that RadioGroup is used for calculations. Now I need to store content of form and want to retrieve it back if I click in Gridview. I can able to store and retrieve textedit, lookup edit and checkedit outside Ribbon Control. How to store and retrieve the RadioGroup from Ribbon Control ??

example for storing CheckBox I used this code

```
 bool temp = barCheckItem1.Checked;
```

In Access Database used "Yes/No" Data Type to store.
For retrieve used this code

```
 barCheckItem1.Checked = reader.GetBoolean(2);
```

this code work fine for CheckBox but I need to Store RadioButton RadioGroup. How to Store & Retrieve it ?? Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store `barEditItem.EditValue` which is the selected item in the `RadioButton`.

I assume you have `int` as `EditValue` from your previous question. So this should be enough.

```
int selectedItem = (int)barEditItem.EditValue;//To Store
```

Store the selected item in DB

```
barEditItem.EditValue = reader.GetInt32(index);//To retrieve back
```

Comment: Hi Sriram. Ya storing as integer and retrieving it, checks the exact Radio Button but in the grid I hide some columns while clicking that radio button this task didn't perform while retrieving. I get normal grid with all columns enables. any idea to solve this ?

Comment: So you mean some events not firing?

Comment: ya. In normal form i used this radio button to hide 2 columns & Perform other calculation in the gridview. While retrieving this things not fired.

Comment: May be that is the expected behavior, check in documentation. IIRC some of events won't fire when you do it manually in devexpress (ex: cellValueChanged won't fire in GridControl and so on), vendor will have a workaround for this.

Comment: May be But normal checkedit in the form is working exactly. I have normal checkedit in form and if checkedit is Checked perform one type oof calculation & when not checked perform other type of calculation. While retrieving I get exact output.

Comment: Hi Sriram, Thanks a lot I solved that Simple recall function according to Editvalue. `if(barEditItem1.EditValue==1){ discount1(); } else { dicount2(); }`.